# set_all to get value from custom model manager in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
Tutorial 
--> consist of published manager which returns queryset when is_published=True

Category
```

In template, I am passing Category object.

```
{% for category in categories %}
{% for tutorial in category.tutorial_set.all %}
   {{ tutorial.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of getting all, I want to get from published manager like: `Tutorials.published.all()`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you can do something like

```
class TutuorialManager(models.Manager):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(is_published = True)
```

then in the views you can do something like..

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for tutorial in category.tutorial_set.published.all %}
       {{ tutorial.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```